# Stored procedure does not return anything

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

It is should be no problem to find but after long hours at my job I cannot notice what I'm doing wrong here.

There is very simple stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProc  
@input char(10)

AS

    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT isonum 
        FROM iso where isonum LIKE '%' + @input + '%'
        ORDER BY isonum
    END
```

when executing a query: select `isonum from iso where isonum like '%2333%'` - I get the data,but when executing the stored procedure:

`exec MyProc '2333'` - I get nothing???

What's wrong here?

Comment: Does it work with an @input of varchar(10)?  Is it padding your variable so that it's searching for `LIKE '%2333      %'`?

Answer (score 2):

Change to `@input char(10)` to  `@input varchar(10)`

your sp is currently running

`isonum from iso where isonum like '%2333      %'`

Comment: you can observe by adding this to your sp: `select '[' + @input + ']'`

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProc  
@input varchar(10)   --<-- Use varchar here 

AS

    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT isonum 
        FROM iso where isonum LIKE '%' + @input + '%'
        ORDER BY isonum
    END
```

'CHAR' or 'NCHAR' fixed data types and they add white spaces to the passed strings if it is less then the maximum length of the data.